# Converting characters to timestamp in an arrow table in R

Tags: r, apache-arrow

I want to convert a character string to a timestamp in an arrow  table.
I am using arrow because I am handling a large number of sizeable csvs.

I succeed in converting the string to a datetime object in a data frame but the same operation produces `NA`s for the arrow table.

How can I convert the string to a timestamp in an arrow table?

Please see the example below.

```
library(arrow)
library(dplyr)

# Set up data
df <- data.frame(
  timestamp_origin = c("1/9/2023 5:52:34 PM", "1/9/2023 5:52:40 PM"),
  value = c(128.094, 128.094)
)

# Working example
df |> 
  mutate(
    timestamp = strptime(
      timestamp_origin, 
      format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", 
      tz = "CET"
    )
  ) 
#>      timestamp_origin   value           timestamp
#> 1 1/9/2023 5:52:34 PM 128.094 2023-01-09 17:52:34
#> 2 1/9/2023 5:52:40 PM 128.094 2023-01-09 17:52:40

# Arrow table produces NAs
df |> 
  arrow_table() |> 
  mutate(
    timestamp = strptime(
      timestamp_origin, 
      format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", 
      tz = "CET"
    )
  ) |> 
  collect()
#>      timestamp_origin   value timestamp
#> 1 1/9/2023 5:52:34 PM 128.094      <NA>
#> 2 1/9/2023 5:52:40 PM 128.094      <NA>
```

Comment: It appears that `strptime`, `as.POSIXct`, and (a little surprising to me) `lubridate::mdy_hms` (and similarly `ymd_hms`) are not (yet?) fully supported in r/arrow.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I did more research and found out that the `p` and the `q` flag are not yet implemented apparantly: https://github.com/apache/arrow/pull/13506

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While [PR13506](https://github.com/apache/arrow/pull/13506) is pending, you can work around this (do as much lazily as possible) with this *hack*.

Steps: determine if it is "PM"; extract the hour; add 12 to hour if PM; recompose `timestamp_origin`; use `strptime` (or whichever) as desired. This all works *lazily* as it succeeds before the `collect()` call.

```r
df <- data.frame(
  timestamp_origin = c("1/9/2023 12:52:34 PM", "1/9/2023 5:52:40 PM"),
  value = c(128.094, 128.094)
)
df |>
  arrow_table() |> 
  mutate(
    isPM = grepl("PM", timestamp_origin),
    isPM = isPM & !grepl(" 12:", timestamp_origin),
    timestamp2 = sub("\\s*[AP]M$", "", timestamp_origin),
    hour = as.integer(sub(".* (\\d{1,2}):.*", "\\1", timestamp2)),
    hour = hour + if_else(isPM, 12, 0),
    timestamp2 = paste0(sub(" .*", " ", timestamp2), hour, sub(".* \\d{1,2}:", ":", timestamp2)),
    timestamp = strptime(
      timestamp2, 
      format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", 
      tz = "CET"
    )
  ) |> 
  select(-isPM, -hour, -timestamp2) |>
  collect()
#       timestamp_origin   value           timestamp
# 1 1/9/2023 12:52:34 PM 128.094 2023-01-09 12:52:34
# 2  1/9/2023 5:52:40 PM 128.094 2023-01-09 17:52:40
```

(The biggest reason I can consider to go through this level or work is if you need to `filter` your data lazily based on ranges of `timestamp`. This code enables this need.)

The second `isPM` is to guard against `12:` being mis-converted to `24:`; sample data has been adjusted to test/confirm this.

Comment: I'm not wholly thrilled with having to do this, but I'm glad I was able to find a way to allow it to work on the "lazy" side of the query. Glad it works for you.

Comment: There is a small mistake in the workaround. The timestamps between noon and 1 PM, e.g. 12:45:45 PM, are converted to 24:XX:XX but should stay at 12:XX:XX. A weird quirk of the AM/PM notation.